# Making Pixel Histogram.ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I am trying to make a pixel histogram for an image. I have an array called **image** that looks like this

```
array([[[ 0,  0, 18, ...,  3,  0, 11],
    [ 5, 18,  0, ..., 16, 16, 11],
    [13,  0,  5, ..., 13, 19, 14],
    ..., 
    [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  9,  0,  8],
    [ 4,  0,  0, ...,  0, 24,  0],
    [19, 12, 16, ...,  0, 16, 21]],

   [[17, 13,  0, ...,  9,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  4,  0,  0],
    [14,  0,  2, ...,  0, 23,  0],
    ..., 
    [ 0,  6, 12, ...,  0, 22,  0],
    [ 0,  0, 20, ...,  9,  7,  0],
    [ 0,  8,  0, ...,  0, 15, 21]],

   [[ 4,  9,  3, ...,  0, 15, 20],
    [21, 16,  0, ...,  0,  8, 18],
    [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0, 18],
    ..., 
    [ 0, 10,  7, ..., 26,  0,  8],
    [15, 25, 16, ..., 17,  0, 18],
    [ 0, 11,  0, ..., 25,  0,  0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I wanted to trim this list using list comphrehension and keeping only the values greater than some max value. But Python is throwing this **ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()** and even though using .any() or .all() makes the program run, it is not the desirable output. What should I do to keep only values in a list that are greater than a specified max value?

```
y, x = image.shape[0],image.shape[1]
pixels = [image[j, i] \
          for i in range(x) \
          for j in range(y) \
          if image[j, i] < max_value]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a boolean array based on your condition and use it to index the original array.

```
>>> img
array([[[200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200]],

       [[200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200]],

       [[200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200],
        [200, 150,  80, 200]]])
>>> b = img < 100
>>> b
array([[[False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False]]], dtype=bool)
>>> pixels = img[b]
>>> pixels
array([80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80])
>>> list(pixels)
[80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
>>>
```

Or simply:

```
>>> img[img < 100]
array([80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80])
>>>
```

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays